# How to label a grid line?

Tags: labeling, grid-lines

I am trying to label the vertical line in the right diagram. PlotLabels doesn't work.

Thank you for any solutions or hints!

[image]

```
Clear[y, a, k, l, c, mpl, mpk, lsupply]
y[a_, k_, l_, c_] := a k^c l^(1 - c)
lsupply[b_, m_, l_] := b + m l
mpl[a_, k_, l_, c_] := Evaluate@D[y[a, k, l, c], l]
mpk[a_, k_, l_, c_] := Evaluate@D[y[a, k, l, c], k]

ClearAll[lE, annotate]
lE = Cases[#, Point[x_] :> x[[1]], All] &;

annotate = ReplaceAll[p : Point[x_] :> {p, Dashed, {Text["E", #, {-1, -1.5}], Text["w", Offset[{5, 0}, {0, #[[2]]}], {-1, -1}], Text["N", Offset[{5, 5}, {#[[1]], 0}], {-1, -1}], Line[{{0, #[[2]]}, #, {#[[1]], 0}}]} &@x}];
annotate2 = ReplaceAll[p : Point[x_] :> {p, Dashed, {Text["E", #, {-1, -1.5}], Text["r", offset[{5, 0}, {0, #[[2]]}], {-1, -1}], Text["K", Offset[{5, 5}, {#[[1]], 0}], {-1, -1}], Line[{{0, #[[2]]}, #, {#[[1]], 0}}]} &@x}];

options1 = Sequence[PlotRange -> {25, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"N", "MP, w"}, PlotLabel -> "Left Diagram", LabelStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> {400, 250}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]];
options2 = Sequence[PlotRange -> {5, 125}, AxesLabel -> {"K", "MP, r"}, PlotLabel -> "Right Diagram", LabelStyle -> Black, MeshFunctions -> {# &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], ImageSize -> {400, 250}];  

Manipulate[Row[
{annotate@(plt1 = 
  Normal@Plot[{mpl[a, k, l, c], lsupply[b, m, l]}, {l, 0, 100}, Evaluate@options1, 
    MeshFunctions -> {mpl[a, k, #, c] - lsupply[b, m, #] &}, 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotLabels -> {"NK:MP(A, K)", "N"}]), 
annotate2@(plt1 = 
  Normal@Plot[mpk[a, kk, lE@plt1, c], {kk, 0, 1000}, 
    Evaluate@options2, Mesh -> {{k}}, 
    GridLines -> {{{k, Orange}}, None}, 
    PlotLabels -> {"K:MP(A, N)"}])}], 
{{a, 250, "TFP, A"}, 1, 400, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k, 350, "K", StandardForm}, 15, 1000, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c, 1/3}, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 150, "Shifting N", StandardForm}, 400, 0.002, 5}, {{m, 5, "Slope N", StandardForm}, 0.1, 25, 1}, {plt1, None}, TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c, k, m}, ContentSize -> {900, 300}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `annotate2` to inject additional text and line primitives. That is, use

```
annotate2 = ReplaceAll[p : Point[x_] :> 
       {p, Dashed, {Text["E", #, {-1, -1.5}], 
        Text["r", Offset[{5, 0}, {0, #[[2]]}], {-1, -1}], 
        Text["K", Offset[{5, 5}, {#[[1]], 0}], {-1, -1}], 
        Line[{{0, #[[2]]}, #, {#[[1]], 0}}], 
        FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> "Plain", 
        FontColor -> Black, FontOpacity -> 1, 
        Text["LABEL", Scaled[{.15, .7}, #], {-1, -1}], 
        Gray, Dashing[{}], AbsoluteThickness[1], 
        Line[{Scaled[{.13, .73}, #], Scaled[{.02, .7}, #]}]} &@x}];
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Is there a possibility to match the formatting of the other labels created by PlotLabels? I tried font sizes 8 and 9 but the font/thickness looks different.

Comment: @Tom, please see the updated version.